# Injecting an object that requires enum in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, enums, constructor, guice

I have an object to be injected that is defined as:

```
    public class EnvironmentModule extends AbstractModule {
    
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
        }
    
        @Provides
        @Singleton
        private String getObject(final Client client) {
            ...
        }
}
```

Client is an enum defined as :

```
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
public enum Client {
    private String name;

    Client(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Client identifyClient(final String clientName) {
   
    }
}
```

This gives me an error-
Could not find a suitable constructor in Client. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private
at Client.class(Client.java:5)
at EnvironmentModule.getObject(EnvironmentModule.java:35)

Please help. What has to be done.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because in your module you do not declare an instance of `Client` to be injected in the scope of the module, so it tries to create one with an empty constructor. This does not work because your enum has two constructors, and guice requires a single empty constructor. The solution to this to create a singleton of your client. I assume the code you omitted in `Client` looks like

```
public enum Client {

    //I assume it works like this
    NORMAL_CLIENT("whatever");

    private String name;

    Client(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Client identifyClient(final String clientName) {
        return Arrays.stream(Client.values())
            .filter(client -> clientName.equals(client.name))
            .findAny()
            //This is dangerous, throw an error if its not found
            .get();
    }
}
```

So we need to create a singleton in the environment module for the client. this would look like

```
public class EnvironmentModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        super.configure();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    private Client getClient() {
        return Client.identifyClient("whatever");
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    private String doWhatever(final Client client) {
        System.out.println("found client " + client);
        return "cool it works";
    }
}
```

invoking the module through

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var envInjector = Guice.createInjector(new EnvironmentModule());
        final var client = envInjector.getInstance(Client.class);
        final var doWhateverString = envInjector.getInstance(String.class);
        System.out.println(doWhateverString);
        System.out.println("found instance " + client);
    }
}
```

we can see

```
found client NORMAL_CLIENT
cool it works
found instance NORMAL_CLIENT
```